# Is there a way to change layout in current Terminator window from the command line?

Tags: bash, terminator

I'm using [Terminator](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html) on Linux Mint 18.

I'm running a bash script in a Terminator window and at some point in there, I would like to change the current Terminator layout programatically to something else.

I notice you can invoke a new instance with a layout already set, using:

`terminator --layout=TheLayoutName`

But is there a command you can pass to the *current* instance of Terminator to change its layout?

Comment: No. I'm asking if it's possible to do things to the current Terminator window from inside a running script, using commands.

Comment: I think it's not possible, but let's wait and see if anyone has a hack for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a start with `xdotool` to send [keybindings](https://linux.die.net/man/1/terminator) to Terminator that alter its layout.

For example, running this in a Terminator window:

`xdotool key ctrl+shift+E` to split the screen horizontally.